# How do I get more pixels on UV map?

Tags: uv, faces, uv-image-editor

I don't understand how to get more pixels on my UV map. What I am doing is creating new image textures having UV grids with 1024, 2048, and 4096 length and width properties, and mapping the color to base color on the shader editor.

[image]

I am then selecting all faces and remapping. I notice that this island, for example, is still staying the same width and height, so no change. Also, the UV rectangle does not show increase pixel density. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: if you change the size of the image the UVs will keep their relative proportion if this is what you're asking

Comment: What I want is to be able to give more UV boxes for my UV faces to map to. I found somewhere else that you cannot change the size of the UV grid, but you can make larger textures with a larger texture size which will give you more UV boxes for your faces (from what I understand so far). That's why I was just trying to create new materials with larger pixel width and height to prove that.

Comment: Nevermind, I just wasn't changing the view on the UV editor. Dumb mistake. thanks.

Comment: oh ok great then ;)